# Limit django queryset by another related table

Tags: django, django-models

Lets say I have 2 django models like this:

```
class Spam(models.Model):
    somefield = models.CharField()

class Eggs(models.Model):
    parent_spam = models.ForeignKey(Spam)
    child_spam = models.ForeignKey(Spam)
```

Given the input of a "Spam" object, how would the django query looks like that:

- Limits this query based on the parent_spam field in the "Eggs" table
- Gives me the corresponding child_spam field
- And returns a set of "Spam" objects

In SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Spam WHERE id IN (SELECT child_spam FROM Eggs WHERE parent_spam = 'input_id')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is only an example, but this model setup doesn't actually validate as it is - you can't have two separate ForeignKeys pointing at the same model without specifying a `related_name`. So, assuming the related names are `egg_parent` and `egg_child` respectively, and your existing Spam object is called `my_spam`, this would do it:

```
my_spam.egg_parent.child_spam.all()
```

or

```
Spam.objects.filter(egg_child__parent_spam=my_spam)
```

Even better, define a `ManyToManyField('self')` on the Spam model, which handles all this for you, then you would do:

```
my_spam.other_spams.all()
```

Comment: The first method gives me a _italic_ 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'child_spam' exception._italic_ The second works like a charm. And the third is not viable since I want to include other fields in "Eggs", so it will be more than just a linking table. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to your sql code you need something like this

```
Spam.objects.filter(id__in= \
    Eggs.objects.values_list('child_spam').filter(parent_spam='input_id'))
```